# How to set CSS width so that the element will have the exact window width?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following CSS code to stretch an element (`<header>` in this example) so that it fits the browser window width:

```
header {
    font-size: small;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
    padding: 3px 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but the problem is that this element, or any to which I apply `width: 100%; overflow: auto;` overflows the window limits:

```
| <--- window width ---> |
|  <--- element width ---> |
```

How can I set the CSS properties so that the element width fits exactly the window width?

```
| <--- window width ---> |
| <--- element width --> |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your padding.  Adding padding adds additional width.  So, your statement is like saying "make it 100% wide, but then add 6px.

If you want it to be fullscreen WITH padding, make it fullscreen, then add a div within it that has the padding.

Answer (score 3):

You should use box-sizing: border-box; That means that the width of an element remains the same either you add border or padding, or even both of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<header>
    <div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And CSS :

```
header{
    font-size: small;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
    width: 100%;
}
header div{
    margin:3px 3px;
    display:block;
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Chouchen/mvs79/

Comment: Thank you, Shikiryu, but Dave answered first. Your answer would do, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove width:100% it should work with the one div solution

```
header {
font-size: small;
color: white;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
padding: 3px 3px;
```

}

usually there's no need to set the width:100% on block elements